# using the codeigniter calendar library to create a multi-user multi-project timesheet

Tags: codeigniter, calendar

I would like to create a timesheet using the codeigniter calendar library. I have used the nettus Day 10 calendar library tutorial to aid me in creating the normal appointment calendar.

What i need is employees to key in the hours they have worked for every project they handle (they handle several at a time) and their hours approved by their immediate supervisors. I need to use codeigniter because the timesheet is just a single module in the HR system i have done in codeigniter. I had an idea of adding extra columns to the calendar template but that has proved futile.

How to create a multi-user multi-project timesheet using a codeigniter calendar library?

Comment: http://www.andyhawthorne.co.uk/using-the-codeigniter-calendar-class/